# Cassandra Scaling: Is it a good idea to use a common mount for multi node Cassandra DB?

Tags: cassandra, storage, cassandra-2.0, mount, nfs

I have Cassandra running in two different DC, and now it's time to scale it up and add more storage.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to add storage on the existing partitions due to restrictions/limitations.  I'd like to know would it be a good idea to use one common mount(NFS) to store the data.  I know Cassandra is distributed across many nodes but can they share a common mount to access the data?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a good idea to do that.  Essentially, you're trading disk I/O for network I/O; so it'll perform terribly.  Also, you're introducing a single point of failure into your cluster.

DataStax published a blog post on this a couple of years ago.  The important thing to remember, is that blog posts don't usually happen about isolated incidents.  They happen because someone sees the same thing causing problems over and over again, and they're trying to stop others from rationalizing that same mistake.

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/impact-of-shared-storage-on-apache-cassandra